# How to release storage using by JavaCv's objects other than IplImages?

Tags: javacv

I have quite big problem with memory leaks in JavaCv. I've already searched a lot and I know that e.g If I allocate some IplImages as below on the left, I can free storage using functions on the right.

```
  cvLoadImage(...)<-->cvReleaseImage(...)        
  cvCloneImage(...)<-->cvReleaseImage(...)        
  CvMat.create(...) <--> cvMatObject.release(...)    
  ...
```

But what If I really have to do something like that:

```
  for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
        CvMatArray array=new CvMatArray(); //or new CvScalar() or something else                      
    //How to deallocate array here If I don't want to get memory leaks?
        }
```

and I want to release storage using by other object (than IplImage's ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. We have to use System.gc() to invoke garbage Collector , which releases memory after old objects:

> for(int i=0;i<100000000;i++){
>         CvMatArray array=new CvMatArray();
>         CvScalar scalar=new CvScalar();
>         System.gc();    }

even in this case:

> for(int i=0;i<100000000;i++){
>         IplImage array=IplImage.create(zmieniane.cvSize(), 8, 1);
>          array.release();
>          System.gc();
>        }

If we don't want to have leaks we have to use GC "manually"